# Quartz Scheduler (Java) - limint on XML-defined jobs

Tags: java, cron, scheduler

I've got about 25 jobs defined in XML on a simple Java Web application I have running with Quartz Scheduler.

I noticed a while back that some of my jobs were not running when they were meant to. The cron expressions are definitely correct, and the xml file is definitely correctly defined - the xml parsing plugin is quite picky and it doesn't mention any errors.

I had all of these jobs categorised into seperate files. To try and isolate the issue, I decided to create one file to house all of the jobs. After doing this, it seems that the first 5 jobs in the file run.

The 6th job won't run, but if I move it up one position in the file (to 5th position) - it runs correctly.

**Quartz.properties:**

```
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true

# ----------------------------- XML Trigger Files ------------------#
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = all_jobs.xml

# ----------------------------- Threads --------------------------- #
# How many jobs can run at the same time?
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=500

# ----------------------------- Plugins --------------------------- #
# Class to load the configuration data for each job and trigger.
# In this example, the data is in an XML file.
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class=org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
```

Is there some sort of thread limit specifically for jobs defined in XML that I obviously don't know about?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There must be some error in your XML. Usually Quartz logs it when the Factory job of re-reading XML works. Quartz XML parser is very particular in what order you are mentioning the properties of a job, Like where should the misfire-instruction of a trigger is mentioned etc. Kindly look for errors, you will easily find the error.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sahil. I included an answer to my own question below. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there were in fact errors in my xml definitions. Another question of mine (a recent lack of errors being logged by tomcat) prevented me from seeing the XMLSchulingDataProcessorPlugin's notifications about malformed XML.

I deployed the application to another server as a last resort and saw that I had accidentally swapped the name of a trigger for the name of a job in the trigger definition which caused Quartz to ignore that job and those defined below it.

Hope this helps somebody!